# Postgresql - could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: postgresql, birt

This question has been asked many times, but the response given / worked for most is not working for me. So, I am suspicious that something else is missing.

```
OS:  $ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-026.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Sun Jul 27 15:55:46 EDT 2014
```

When I try to start PostGreSQL, I get the following error :

```
[reportadmin /opt/birt/modules/BIRTiHub]$ ./startPostgreSQL.sh

Starting startpostgresql at Fri 05/15/2015 08:03:29

AC_SERVER_HOME=/opt/BIRTiHubFType/modules/BIRTiHub/iHub
2015-05-15 12:03:30 UTC  27379 LOG:  loaded library "pg_stat_statements"
2015-05-15 12:03:30 UTC  27379 FATAL:  could not create shared memory segment: Cannot allocate memory
2015-05-15 12:03:30 UTC  27379 DETAIL:  Failed system call was shmget(key=8433001, size=290635776, 03600).
2015-05-15 12:03:30 UTC  27379 HINT:  This error usually means that PostgreSQL's request for a shared memory segment exceeded available memory or swap space, or exceeded your kernel's SHMALL parameter.  You can either reduce the request size or reconfigure the kernel with larger SHMALL.  To reduce the request size (currently 290635776 bytes), reduce PostgreSQL's shared memory usage, perhaps by reducing shared_buffers or max_connections.
    The PostgreSQL documentation contains more information about shared memory configuration.
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Also, I have adjusted the shmmax and shmall values to be greater than and less than (respect) the requested value.

```
[root /opt/birt]$ sysctl -p
....
kernel.msgmnb = 65536
kernel.msgmax = 65536
kernel.shmmax = 68719476736
kernel.shmall = 134217728
```

In other words:

```
shmall    =134217728
Requested =290635776
shmmax    =68719476736
```

Any idea what could be wrong ?

D

Comment: What is your postgres version?

Comment: Note the _Cannot allocate memory_ error which differs from the _Invalid argument_ you'd get if `shmmax` was too low. You need to first rule out the obvious, that the OS doesn't have a block of 290MB of contiguous physical RAM available, which would be what the error indicates.

Comment: The mem profile out of "top" is:
Mem:    604480k total,   595376k used,     9104k free,    51452k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,    52760k cached

 so, that shouldnt be a problem

Comment: This Postgres sql installation comes with birt ihub BI software. Unfortunatey, I havent been able to start this even once. So, cant check the version.

Comment: ERR- I can see the problem. Only 9 MB free. This is a AWS Free instance.. thats why. Should fix this first. Thanks.